# need assistance with via code for picture upload

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Cont_attachthumb()
Dim PicFile As FileDialog
With Sheet2
  Set PicFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With PicFile
    .Title = "Select A Content Picture"
    .Filters.Add "All Picture Files", ".jpg, *jpeg, *.gif, *.png, *bmp", 1

    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

    Sheet2.Range("R11").Value = .SelectedItems(1) 'Put File Name in R11
  End With
If .Range("B3").Value = False Then .Range("M" & Sheet2.Range("B2").Value).Value = .Range("R11").Value

Cont_displaythum

NoSelection:
  End With
End Sub
```

I get a run time 91 error 
object variable or with block variable not set error

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQukL.png)

Comment: Ignore my last comment. The indentation was throwing me off. Upon which line do you get this error? The `End With` inside your `NoSelection:` block is very strange. Perhaps move that up above the `NoSelection:` line and rerun.

Comment: .Title = "Select A Content Picture"
run time error 91
object variable or with block variable is not set

Answer (score 1):

You are setting 2 `With` statements:
   1. `With Sheet2`
   2. `With PicFile`
one inside the other, even though they are not connected or necessary.

Second part, `If .Range("B3").Value = False Then .Range("M" & Sheet2.Range("B2").Value).Value = .Range("R11").Value` is most likely related to `Sheet2` object, so it needs to be inside the `With Sheet2` statement, so as @JNevill wrote in his comment, you need to move the `End With` after this line.

More explanation inside the code's comments below:

***Modified Code***

```
Sub Cont_attachthumb()

Dim PicFile As FileDialog

Set PicFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With PicFile
    .Title = "Select A Content Picture"
    .Filters.Add "All Picture Files", "*.jpg, *jpeg, *.gif, *.png, *bmp", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

    Sheet2.Range("R11").Value = .SelectedItems(1) 'Put File Name in R11
End With

With Sheet2
    If .Range("B3").Value = False Then .Range("M" & .Range("B2").Value).Value = .Range("R11").Value
    ' moved this ^ row above the End With
End With

Cont_displaythum ' <-- I hope this is a Sub defined somewhere else

NoSelection:

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response, still get the same error

Comment: the error appears to come from:
.Title = "Select A Content Picture"
    .Filters.Add "All Picture Files", ".jpg, *jpeg, *.gif, *.png, *bmp", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

Comment: @UzeyirChalabi try now, was missing a `*` before the `.jpg`

Comment: still get a runtime error 91,
object variable or with block variable not set
the error points to the title, if I comment it out the the error points to the next line

Answer (score 0):

The separator is not "," but ";" It seems to be.

change this

```
.Filters.Add "All Picture Files", ".jpg, *jpeg, *.gif, *.png, *bmp", 1
```

to

```
.Filters.Add "All Picture Files", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png; *bmp", 1
```